# Adding relationship property in neo4j REST API's batch operation

Tags: neo4j

This JSON format loads relationships successfully:

```
{"method":"POST","to":"/node/25612/relationships","id":25612,"body":{"to":"25614","type":"father"}}
```

What is the format to add a "weight" property to the relationship?

Comment: That's not CSV, but JSON. Where is this used? The REST API for creating relationships with properties is documented [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/#rest-api-create-a-relationship-with-properties).

Comment: Yes, JSON. I've looked at the documentation and tried several formats, such as {"method":"POST","to":"/node/3/relationships","id":3,"body":{"to":"608","type":"father","property":{"wt":"500"}}} but they do not work. Asking for suggestions.

Comment: Where are you trying to use this data? The REST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the REST API's `batch` operation, the `body.data` object specifies relationship properties, as in:

```
{
  "method":"POST",
  "to":"/node/25612/relationships",
  "id":25612,
  "body":{
    "to":"25614",
    "type":"father",
    "data": {
      "weight": 175
    }
  }
}
```